# How to link RadioButtons with images in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to make an app that shows the name for each character in Ninja Turtles, I've made the 4 RadioButtons and imported the pictures. Whenever I run the the app, it crashes.

The XML is:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Leo"
    android:id="@+id/leo"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="pickTurtle"
      />


<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mike"
    android:text="Mike"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="pickTurtle"
    android:clickable="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/raph"
    android:text="Raph"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="pickTurtle"
    android:clickable="true" />

<RadioButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/don"
    android:text="Don"
    android:checked="false"
    android:onClick="pickTurtle"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/a"
android:src="@drawable/a"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="info"
/>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="17032dp"
    android:layout_height="242dp"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:src="@drawable/b"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="info"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/c"
    android:src="@drawable/c"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="info"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/d"
    android:src="@drawable/d"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="info"
    />
```

The Java code is:

public void pickTurtle(View view) {

```
  ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b);


    if (view.getId() == R.id.leo) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.mike) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.don) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);

    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.raph) {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d); } }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove  android:onClick="pickTurtle" from radiobuttons

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroupdid);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
       if (checkedId == R.id.leo) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.a);

} else if (checkedId == R.id.mike) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.b);

} else if (checkedId == R.id.don) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.c);

} else if (checkedId == R.id.raph) {
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.d); } } 
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, something was wrong with my code,,,,, now it works